# Node.js express-jwt with express-unless gives a warning "Object is possibly 'undefined'"

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, express-jwt

Using typescript and nodejs, and express-jwt for validation of authenticity.
When we use the express-jwt together with unless, as can be seen as below, tslint is complaining about the possible undefined value returned after the unless function.

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as jwt from "express-jwt";
import * as http from "http";

const refConfig = {hash: 'mycompletelysecrethashstring', othersetting: 1 };

app.use("/api", jwt({ secret: refConfig.hash }).unless({ path: ["/api/auth/signin"] }));
app.set("port", 8000);
const server: http.Server = app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log("Server is now running on port " + server.address().port);
});
```

The error message is as below:

```
[ts] Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Is it possible to get rid of this warning, and if so, what is the correct way of doing so?

The issue is with the below line:

```
app.use("/api", jwt({ secret: refConfig.hash }).unless({ path: ["/api/auth/signin"] }));
```

As far as I can tell, TypeScript compiler is complaining that the list of routes might be an empty list at the end of unless. Given that the original list is a superset of "/api/auth/signin" it is not a valid concern, but I can't get rid of the warning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're missing it from the example, you need to create the `app` instance :

```
const app = express() 
app.use(/*...*/)
```

Also, from your example, `jwt` is not a function but an object. Try,

```
import jwt from 'express-jwt'
```

Comment: This is only the part of the application, and everything else is working fine except the warning on the line mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `refConfig.hash` without determining whether `refConfig` itself is first defined.

You should instead do something like:

```
if (refConfig) {
   app.use("/api", jwt({ secret: refConfig.hash }).unless({ path: ["/api/auth/signin"] }));
}
```

A more complete check would be to validate your configuration beforehand and deal with the case where it is incomplete (e.g. exit early with an error for the user).

Comment: thank you for your reply, but refConfig is already defined in the original code, and it is certainly not the reason. I have updated the code in the question to reflect this fact. Thank you for the heads-up.

Comment: Please share the line number the TypeScript error deters to.

Comment: Thank you elithrar. I made the changes to the question to provide a more exact question.